# Compiling Bootstrap in LESS - How can I have a different navbar height for mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

My entire AngularJS website is reponsive. It is responsive to the screen size & loads the same pages for mobile, desktop, and tablet. However, I am having trouble getting the navbar to be a separate height on different devices in a responsive way.

Mostly, I just want the navbar to load at a slimmer height on mobile so that more of the screen space can be utilized for actual content that the user wants to see.

Right now, I am setting the height variable in `variables.less` which is where I know how to alter navbar height settings currently.

**Variables.less**

```
// Basics of a navbar
@navbar-height:                    64px; // most relevant line!
@navbar-margin-bottom:             @line-height-computed;
@navbar-border-radius:             @border-radius-base;
@navbar-padding-horizontal:        floor((@grid-gutter-width / 2));
@navbar-padding-vertical:          ((@navbar-height - @line-height-computed) / 2);
@navbar-collapse-max-height:       340px;

@navbar-default-color:             @gray-light;
@navbar-default-bg:                #fff;
@navbar-default-border:            transparent;
```

OK, so that is great, but I want `64px` height to be set for desktop/tablet **but** `38px` height to be set for navbar height on mobile screens.

I have already tried over-riding the navbar height in my local CSS with a media query but even with the `!important` flag it is not working to set the navbar to another height.

**App.less** <-- this doesn't work :(

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 35px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse ul li a {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .navbar-brand li a {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```

**NOTE** I am using Bootstrap 3. Also, if it makes any difference,  Bootstrap is imported in the main `app.less` file like so: `@import "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";`

What should I do? How can this be done in a responsive fashion?

(*A.K.A. without making an entirely different site for mobile*)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you inspected the navbar with the dev tools to see what css is being applied?

Comment: it looks like min-height is being applied to the .navbar at 64px tall

Comment: well that would be your problem - min-height always overrides height AND max-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment above, I suggest you set min-height to 35px in your media query

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 35px;
  }
```

Comment: woops, that was all I had to do

Answer (score 1):

I think what prevents you to set the height is the `min-height` property set to the element with class `navbar`.

Adding `min-height: 35px` would be enough:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 35px;
    min-height: 35px;
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

   .navbar {
    height: 35px !important;
  }

  .navbar-collapse ul li a {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .navbar-brand li a {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

}
```